# select checkbox by its value and make it checked

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="productIdCheckbox" value="@item.Id">
```

To check it I run this code:

```
function checkItem(elem) {
        var id = $(elem).attr("id");
        $("input[name='productIdCheckbox'][value='" + id + "']").attr("checked", this.checked);
    };
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: Where is `checkItem` code

Comment: In `this.checked`, this refers to the calling element, make sure that element which calling `checkItem` function has `checked` attribute

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar, You're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
$("input[name='productIdCheckbox'][value='" + id + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Comment: You need to use `prop` to set checked otherwise the value will not be posted

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
$("input[value='+id +']").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Comment: you missed `"` at the end of `$("input[value='+id +'])`

Comment: yea sorry for that ,  thanx